# Django parent_id - should it be NULL, blank, or 0?

Tags: django, django-models

When I have top-level tree items, should i consider using `blank=True`, `null=True` or `default=0` ?

What complications can arise in which of those cases, and therefore which should I use?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `blank=True` or `default=0` then you will be expected to have parents that match that when you move to a database that actually supports referential integrity. *Always* use `NULL`/`None`, unless you have a good reason for using something else.

Comment: So I should put `null=True`, right? What does it mean to "move to a database that actually supports referential integrity"?

Comment: MySQL is... a little lax when it comes to referential integrity; just because a field is *declared* as a `FOREIGN KEY` doesn't mean that it actually *cares*. PostgreSQL on the other hand will pitch a fit if a matching record isn't found on the other side.

Comment: aaah, I see. I am on MySQL, but I will use NULL as per your recommendation for good practice. Thank you mighty helpful gurus